Blender 4.2.3 LTS and Blender 3.5 Emission material not working
I followed Kaizen's YouTube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSrjDgWWlWs
and copied everything to a T.  First in Blender 4.2.3LTS , but my emission doesn't work.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lrZm_xgmAJaMoTGpzF2Qty1t-HHA6lS4/view?usp=sharing
so re-did everything again using Blender 3.5 , still emission not working
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M2zOTUJc3JQMfp-XlaGdO6W78z6SjFBP/view?usp=sharing
I can see my Waveform in ViewPort Shading Material preview, but it's pitch black in ViewPort Shading Render Preview
What did I miss out?  What did I do wrong?
The only workaround that I can think of and applied in Blender 3.5 is to create a flat plane behind the waveform just to make it visible
Also, as always I use EEVEE coz can't wait forever for Cycles
Another thing is that my Audio WaveForm finishes earlier than the music.  Is it because of I switched frames from 24 to 25 frames per second?
Thank in Advance Blender community

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

You have not chosen any material in your Set Material node. Yes, it says "Material", but even though your default material has the same name, the dark grey color in which it is written there indicates it is just a placeholder telling you to choose a "Material" (if you had renamed it to "WaveForm" like in the other file, it would have been more obvious that this was not chosen in the node):

As soon as you have chosen a material there - the name "Material" is now white indicating you have set a material with this specific name - your curve shows the emission:

That was the 4.2.3 LTS file. In the 3.5 file it is even more obvious, the Set Material slot is empty:

Unfortunately Kaizen does not really show this, at 1:45 he just says adding a Set Material node would allow you to use the material on the object. So although he calls it beginner friendly, it still is a tutorial that requires users to be not completely new to this stuff. However someone in the comments has the exact same problem like you and the answer is already given there.
In general you can say, any kind of geometry that was created inside the Geometry Nodes nodetree needs to have a material assigned and  specified by a Set Material node, otherwise it will look like an object which has no material at all.

OHHHH!!!   set the material   IN THE NODE ...   I've been setting  the material in the usual material setting on the right side pane...  I feel so stupid...   but now am a step wiser due to this.  Thank you so much sensei !!!  I am your ever grateful padawan      now, if you'll excuse me, I'm gonna spend the next hour flogging myself    ;D

@MiahOng You might consider accepting the answer if it helped you. By the way, with the Set Material node you can even assign materials to Geometry Nodes elements which are not on the object itself, but instead use materials from other objects in the scene.

I did accept the answer and YOUR answer Sensei BrinkMann helped me to move on to proceed with my project.  I missed it by ONE click, and one click can mean success or failure.  Thank You for helping learners like me in the way of the ... BLENDER   ;D

@MiahOng No, you have not accepted the answer, you have upvoted it. Accepting the answer means clicking on the tick mark so that it becomes green: accepted answer. This is not only for showing appreciation, it also helps people to filter for questions that have not been answered yet and might need more attention.

Ohhh!   So sorry sensei,  I'm so new to this and forum ettiquette if this is what it's called.  Tick mark = Check Mark on left side  after ANSWER and the UP / DOWN arrows with it.  It is now green.  Will remember that in the future....
